# x-axis graph question. very short question

Tags: calculus, geometry

I have the following equation

$(x+a)y=0$

where x and y are non-negative variables. and a is strictly positive.

So, the graph go this equation is x-axis graph? Is this right?

Regardless of value of x, y always equals to zero.

Please confirm me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ (x+a)y = 0 \iff y = 0 \text{ or } x+a=0$$
The second can never happen because (since $x$ is non-negative) $x+a \geq a > 0$, so the only solutions are $y=0$, $x \geq 0$. The graph is not the whole $x$-axis, but only the positive part of it ($x \geq 0$).

Comment: thanks a lot :)